# Loop through string of dropdown options and select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select an option in a string, where the string will be the contents of a dropdown, but I dont know how to loop through the string as an object please.
In the example I would like "Saab" to be selected and the string alerted.

```
var x = '<select><option>Volvo</option>   <option>Saab</option>   <option>Mercedes</option>   <option>Audi</option> </select>';

$.each($(x), function(index, value) { 
    if ($(this).val() == "Saab"){
        $(this).attr("selected","selected")
    }
});
alert(x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by turning the string into a jQuery object:

```
var x = $(x);
```

Then just select the correct option and set it as selected:

```
$('option:contains("Saab")', x).prop('selected', true);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BZmjL/1/)

Comment: thank you, would it be possible to get it back into string format e.g. var x = '<select><option>Volvo</option>   <option selected='selected'>Saab</option>   <option>Mercedes</option>   <option>Audi</option> </select>';

Comment: @PeterPitLock - Sure, just use another variable than `x`, or use `toString()` - See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BZmjL/6/) -

Comment: seems I'm buggered unfortunately, everything works fine except when I try to get it back to the string format, seems i'll have to settle with x.replace('<option>Saab</option>','<option selected='selected'>Saab</option>' ) , thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('option', x), function(index, value) { 
    if ($(this).text() == "Saab"){
        $(this).attr("selected","selected")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in an HTML page? If yes, why not just use something like $("option").each()?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to loop, jquery can do that for ya

```
$(x).children('option:contains("Saab")').attr('selected','selected');
```

ref: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: PS: When you alert(x), you dont see it selected, you have to append to body

Comment: I didn't know 'text' was an attribute for an option element? Not sure this would work.

Comment: Oops i forgot the contains things :(